# JSLint friendly version of AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, jslint

Is there a version of AngularJS that follows JSLint Standards?

I installed JSLint to help guaranty proper formatting of the JS in my project, however, when I try to build, I get over 1000 JSLint complaints relating to Angular alone.

(this is in an MVC product, so it will get minimized in production anyway.)

Comment: (JSHint)[http://jshint.com/] is much more flexible. You can predefine variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSLint (or any linter) should be used to evaluate the quality of your own code, not that of libraries your code depends on, since there are no guarantees about the quality of those libraries. Configure whatever you are using to run JSLint to not run on core Angular files.

I'm not sure how you are running JSLint, but if you are using JSLintNet for ASP.NET MVC (just a guess, since you mentioned it was an MVC project), you can create a file called JSLintNet.json in the root of your project and put this in it (with your own paths):

```
{
    "ignore": [
        "/path/to/angular.js",
        "/path/to/angular/folder"
    ]
}
```

and it won't try to evaluate Angular's code.

If you also want to ignore global variables like "angular" in your own code, you can put this line at the top of each JS file:

```
/*global angular */
```

Again, if you are using JSLintNet, instead of putting the above line in each file, you can put the following line in the JSLintNet.json file:

```
"globalVariables": ["angular"]
```